# In Elasticsearch, why do I get an error message "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default"

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write a query to return unique cities. My code is:

```
GET /files/_doc/_search
{
  "size":"0",
  "aggs" : {
    "uniq_cities" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "cities" }

    }
  }
}
```

I have an error message as follows:

> Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on
>   [cities] in order to load fielddata in memory by
>   uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use
>   significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.

When I run

```
GET /files/_doc/_mapping
```

I get:

```
"cities" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "fields" : {
    "keyword" : {
      "type" : "keyword",
      "ignore_above" : 256
    }
  }
}
```

Based on the above, it seems that I already have a keyword field. How do I fix the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default" because you are trying to apply aggregation on a text field `cities`. It also has a sub field `keyword` whose data type is `keyword`. Therefore, apply the aggregation on `cities.keyword` field as below:

```
GET /files/_doc/_search
{
  "size":"0",
  "aggs" : {
    "uniq_cities" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "cities.keyword" }

    }
  }
}
```